# SoapUI. Ошибка "unsupported content-type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]"

Tags: soap

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, при оправке POST-запроса в SoapUI, который содержит русские буквы, в ответе возвращается ошибка:
`unsupported content-type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]`

Raw:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 28 Feb 2017 09:00:38 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

Использую SoapUI, Rest-project. В header указаны и `Content-Type: application/json`, и `charset=UTF-8`.
Если в post-запросе содержится только латиница никаких проблем не возникает

Спасибо.

Comment: русские буквы точно в UTF-8? может случайно используется другая кодировка?

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решение нашлось. Нужно в Property метода было явно указать encoding = UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Для всех методов изначально устанавливайте 'Encoding' = 'UTF-8'
Иначе потом очень сильно устанете менять ручками в своих кейсах (ну тут, как вариант, можно открыть XML файл через текстовый редактор, так будет быстрее)